# PHP PDO execute error 42000

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting a 42000 PDO error, I know this has to do with MySQL reserved words and I have put all my column names in backticks. However, this has not solved my problem. I am using Xampp on Windows 10, I am wondering if it could be an Apache or MySQL error and not a PHP syntax error?

```
class ItemList {

private $pdo;

public function add() {
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `item` (`ID`, `userID`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `link`, `image`) 
                                           VALUES (NULL, :userID, :name, :description, :price, :link, :image)");

  $stmt->execute(array(':userID' => $_SESSION['userID'], 
                        ':name' => $_REQUEST["name"],
                        ':name' => $_REQUEST["name"],
                        ':description' => $_REQUEST["description"],
                        ':price' => $_REQUEST["price"],
                        ':link' => $_REQUEST["link"],
                        ':image' => $_REQUEST["image"]
                       )); 
    }
}
```

I know this may be a stupid easy answer and that I may just be stuck and I know there are some similar questions out there already. But any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: this could be as simple as changing `VALUES (NULL,` to `VALUES ('',` - since am betting that your ID column does not accept NULL values and is and AI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO item 
    ( userID, `name`, description, price, link, image) 
    VALUES ( :userID, :name, :description, :price, :link, :image)");
```

name is a reserved word in MySQL you only need it in backticks, also NULL values are not necessary for your statements.

Comment: I do not see any appreciable difference compared to my answer of 15 days ago .. and it seems strange that two users have the same name ..

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you arr assigning a null value to a column that don't admit it.

if you are using an autoincrement ID you could omit the null value in value clause  and the id reference in into clause

```
public function add() {
     $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `item` 
        ( `userID`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `link`, `image`) 
 VALUES ( :userID, :name, :description, :price, :link, :image)");


}
```

Comment: To whoever upvoted this answer: if you care to learn PHP basic syntax, you would know that it's impossible to get a PHP array with duplicated keys. Least a null value would impose any problem